# Calling typeperf from Go code to receive system information

Tags: windows, go

I'm trying to get a list of processes including their current load.
`typeperf "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -sc 1` seems to give me the output I want. Executing this from `cmd` works.

Now I try to call that command from my Go code

```
// Command to list processes
cmdPS := exec.Command("typeperf", "\"\\Process(*)\\% Processor Time\"", "-sc", "1")
cmdPS.Stdout = &buff
cmdPS.Stderr = &errBuff
err := cmdPS.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Err: %s", buff.String())
    return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "Failed to call: ps ax -o")
}
```

This results in:

```
Exiting, please wait...
Error: No valid counters.

Note:
  In order to use typeperf, you must either be a member of the local
  Performance Log Users group, or the command must be executed from an
  elevated command window.
```

Is the way I format the command string wrong? I would expect that executing this command directly and through Go it would run with the same permissions.

Comment: No need to quote your arguments as these are not interpreted by a shell.

Comment: @Volker I thought I would construct it _exactly_ as I type it into cmd.... removing the esacaped quotes solved it. Feel free to add as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to remove the escaped quotes. The shell (or the cmd in this case) will handle the arguments for you.

However, running `typeperf "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -sc 1`  yeilds to the following on my machine.

```
Error: No valid counters.

Note:
  In order to use typeperf, you must either be a member of the local
  Performance Log Users group, or the command must be executed from an
  elevated command window.
```